# Adding Image To Project

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am adding image to project image.png and image@2x.png to my application @2x indicated for retina display,  So its do have some image quality where its support for the resolution of the retina.  When I am adding the image.png and image@2x.png to my application project its not allowing to add same name!

So,  How to differentiate the two images for my project so it need to support the lower and higher version! and display quality! too

I am hoping some one will figure it out with this issue!

@ thanks in advance

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. adding **image.png** and **image@2x.png** shouldn't give you an error since they are not the same name. Make sure you already do not have one of those files in your project. What errors are you seeing? Maybe post a screenshot or the error text.

Comment: @WrightsCS: That might be because she might have already added both **image.png** and **image@2x.png** and hence it is already in kiran's project bundle and hence kiran might be getting error about "same name" issue. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @ParthBhatt *Make sure you already do not have one of those files in your project.*

Comment: @WrightsCS: Yes you are correct. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step-1:** You need to search for **image.png** and **image@2x.png** in your files and groups and delete them. When you right click on them and click Delete, it will show up following image:

[image]

Here from the image, you need to click on "**Delete**" and not "**Remove References Only**".

**Step-2:** Once you do that, you just need to re-add the files to the project by just dragging them into the Resources folder. Also make sure you select "**Copy files into project directory if necessary**" as shown in below image:

[image]

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The @2x is part of the filename. Xcode will let you add two files with different filenames. Then you call it in your code, something like this:

```
anImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

And on retina capable devices like the iPhone4/4S it'll load image@2x.png if it can. Note that APIs like `UIImage`s `initWithContentsOfFile:` do not respect the @2x filenaming convention.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already have an image in your resource folder with the same name. Delete any references to an image called "image.png" then drag both of them into your project.